# Estimate the size of the extracted files before extraction a `tar.gz` archive?

Tags: command-line, tar, gzip

Before using `tar` to extract a `.tar.gz` archive, it is possible to get an estimate of how large the extracted files are in total?

Comment: Try `gzip -l archive.tar.gz`

Answer (score 22):

**For `gzip`**:

```
$ gzip -l binutils-2.24.tar.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
           30809913           186997248  83.5% binutils-2.24.tar
```

Now you see a compressed and an uncompressed size of the content.

Or alternatively use that command:

```
$ zcat binutils-2.24.tar.gz | wc --bytes
186997248
```

**For `bzip2`**, there is `bzcat`:

```
$ bzcat binutils-2.24.tar.bz2 | wc -c
186997248
```

**For `rar`**, use:

```
$ unrar l archive.rar
...
    1        465769002 102749558  22%
```

In the last line of the output there is the original size in bytes (the second digit).

**For `zip`**, use

```
$ unzip -l archive.zip
...
700136                     4 files
```

Also the last line (the first digit)

Comment: Thanks. WHat if it is other common types' compression files, e.g. .bz, .rar, .zip, ...?

Comment: @Tim see my edit

Comment: Note that the methods which use `-l` or `l` are _much_ more efficient than the `*cat` methods. The former methods simply read the file size data from the archive header, the later methods extract the entire archive contents.

Comment: For **xz** `xz -l file.xz`